# JIRA JQL to search for stories where all subtasks have been closed

Tags: jira, jql

I would like to search for all open tickets within a specific project where all subtasks associated with each individual ticket have been closed.

I'm using cloud-hosted JIRA. Does anybody know what query I can use for this?

Answer (score 3):

I already answered a question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107401/jql-5-1-query-does-not-display-a-particular-field/28108373#28108373). It looks exactly like what you want, try searching a little better next time.

**Edit:** Answer included

```
project=PROJECT_KEY AND resolution = Unresolved AND 
    issuefunction not in parentsOf("project=PROJECT_KEY AND resolution = Unresolved") AND  
    issuefunction in parentsOf("project=PROJECT_KEY")
```

Comment: Please include you answer here as well - if, for whatever reason, the other question will be deleted, your link is going to break.